# Laravel Eloquent complex where

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How to convert this code to Laravel (Eloquent):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts p WHERE (p.is_public = 1)';

if (isset($date)){ //$date format is '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
    $query .= ' AND (p.created_at > "'.$date.'")';
}

if (isset($search)){
    $query .= ' AND ((p.title LIKE "%'.$search.'%") OR (p.body LIKE "%'.$search.'%"))';
}
```

Comment: Can we maybe see what you already tried to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: All the answers can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent. Try to solve it yourself first and then, if it still doesn't work, ask and show us what you did so far and what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Share what you have tried?

Comment: `$query = DB::table('posts AS p')
    ->where('p.is_public',1);

if (isset($date)){
    $query->where('p.created_at', '>', $date));
}

if (isset($search)){
    $search = '%'.$search.'%';
    $query->where('p.title', 'like', $search)
        ->orWhere('p.body', 'like', $search)
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

assume Post is your model

```
$posts = Post::where('is_public', 1);
if (isset($date)) { 
    $posts->where('created_at', '>', $date);
}
if (isset($search)) {
    $posts->where(function($query) use ($search) {
                 $query->where('title', 'like', "%'.$search.'%")
                  ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%'.$search.'%");
             });
}
$posts = $posts->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Example code : assume Post is your model

```
$getPosts=Post::query()->where('is_public',1);

$getPosts->when(isset($date),function($q) use ($date){
    $q->where('created_at','>',$date);
 });

$getPosts->when(isset($search),function($q) use ($search){
    $q->where('title','like','%'.$search.'%');
    $q->orWhere('body','like','%'.$search.'%');
 });
$posts=$getPosts->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$query = Post::where('is_public', '1');

if (isset($date)){ //$date format is '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
    $query->where('created_at', '>', $date);
}

if (isset($search)){
    $query->whereRaw('title LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR body LIKE "%'.$search.'%"');
}

$posts = $query->get();
```